# Grails 3 integration tests throw "No Session found for current thread" hibernate exception when saving entities

Tags: hibernate, grails, integration-testing, spock

I have the following grails Specification test

```
@Integration
@Rollback
class WebAppointmentControllerSpec extends Specification {


    Clinic clinic
    Practitioner practitioner
    Patient patient
    User user;
    Address address1

    def setup() {
        this.address1 = new Address(locality: 'Calgary', administrativeArea: 'Alberta', country: Country.findByCca2('CA'), postalCode: 'T1A1A1', addressLine1: "123 Tooth Street SW")
        address1.save(failOnError: true)
        this.clinic = new Clinic(name: 'Test Clinic 1', address: address1, primaryEmail: 'test@clinic1.com', primaryPhone: phone1, website: 'http://www.clinic1.com', timeZone: DateTimeZone.forID('America/Edmonton'))
        clinic.save(failOnError: true)
        this.practitioner = new Practitioner(admin: false, firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith', clinic: this.clinic, primaryTelephone: StringUtil.formatTelephoneNumber('1234567890'))
        practitioner.save(failOnError: true)
        user = new User(email: 'user12345@appreciado.com', passwordHash: BCryptUtil.hashpw('testtest', BCryptUtil.gensalt(10)), enabled: true, accountExpired: false, accountLocked: false, credentialsExpired: false, secretKey: new SecretKey(value: 'dRZbYLVN=yjBW17V09Bf'), emailVerified: true, acceptTermsAndConditions: true, acceptPrivacyTerms: true).save(failOnError: true)
        this.patient = new Patient(user: user, firstName: 'User2', lastName: 'User2Last', primaryTelephone: '+14035551212', dateOfBirth: StringUtil.parseRegistrationDate("1979/02/02"), group: patientGroup, points: 200).save(failOnError: true)
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }


    void "Anonymous user cannot update appointment status"() {
        given:
            RestBuilder rest = new RestBuilder()
            Appointment appointment = new Appointment(patient: this.patient, practitioner: this.practitioner, clinic: this.clinic, dateAndTime: LocalDateTime.parse('2015-03-15T10:00:00'), endDateAndTime: LocalDateTime.parse('2015-03-15T10:30:00'), lastUpdatedBy: this.practitioner)
            appointment.save(failOnError: true)
            appointment.save()

        when: "The home page is visited"
            RestResponse restResponse = rest.post("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/arrivals/$arrivalid/status");

        then: "A 401 error is sent"
            restResponse.status == 401
    }
}
```

When it runs I get the following error...

org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread

```
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsSessionContext.currentSession(GrailsSessionContext.java:117)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.SessionFactoryProxy.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryProxy.java:148)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateSession.createQuery(HibernateSession.java:154)
at org.grails.orm.hibernate.HibernateSession.createQuery(HibernateSession.java:148)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.AbstractFindByFinder.buildQuery(AbstractFindByFinder.java:39)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.AbstractFindByFinder$1.doInSession(AbstractFindByFinder.java:24)
at org.grails.datastore.mapping.core.DatastoreUtils.execute(DatastoreUtils.java:302)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.AbstractFinder.execute(AbstractFinder.java:41)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.AbstractFindByFinder.doInvokeInternal(AbstractFindByFinder.java:22)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.DynamicFinder.invoke(DynamicFinder.java:156)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.finders.DynamicFinder.invoke(DynamicFinder.java:356)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.methodMissing(GormStaticApi.groovy:112)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.internal.StaticMethodInvokingClosure.call(StaticMethodInvokingClosure.groovy:32)
at com.appreciado.server.api.WebAppointmentControllerSpec.setup(WebAppointmentControllerSpec.groovy:36)
```

Is there some way I can enable a hibernate session for my integration test?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently you cannot save entities in the `setup` method and should rename the method something else (`setupData` for example) and call it directly from your test method in the `given` block.

This is fixed in the soon to be released 3.0.10 version:https://github.com/grails/grails-core/commit/cc2f2ed86d18fded831242d0c8d2d1ee885fc8a5